# [Jammy]: puppet-agent has no installation candidate despite following instructions

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, puppet

Goal: have Puppet 6 agent on a ubuntu:jammy docker container to test Puppet scripts.

I have added Puppetlabs repositories, ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` but still `apt-get install puppet-agent` fails with error 'has no installation candidate`.

Instructions I followed: [Puppet instructions](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/install_puppet.html#install_puppet)

What am I doing wrong?

### Instructions of how to reproduce

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:jammy

EXPOSE 80

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN yes| unminimize
RUN apt-get install apt-utils -y

# packages we need
RUN apt-get install unzip -y
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install puppet -y
```

#### Commands on the Docker container terminal

```
root@6d2e2ea018b6:/# history 
    1  wget https://apt.puppet.com/puppet6-release-jammy.deb
    2  dpkg -i puppet6-release-jammy.deb 
    3  apt-get update -y
    4  apt-get upgrade -y
    5  apt-get install puppet-agent
```

#### Command output

```
root@6d2e2ea018b6:/# wget https://apt.puppet.com/puppet6-release-jammy.deb
--2023-06-07 11:59:24--  https://apt.puppet.com/puppet6-release-jammy.deb
Resolving apt.puppet.com (apt.puppet.com)... 52.222.139.62, 52.222.139.78, 52.222.139.20, ...
Connecting to apt.puppet.com (apt.puppet.com)|52.222.139.62|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11702 (11K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: 'puppet6-release-jammy.deb'

puppet6-release-jammy.deb                       100%[=====================================================================================================>]  11.43K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2023-06-07 11:59:24 (127 MB/s) - 'puppet6-release-jammy.deb' saved [11702/11702]

root@6d2e2ea018b6:/# dpkg -i puppet6-release-jammy.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package puppet6-release.
(Reading database ... 10920 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack puppet6-release-jammy.deb ...
Unpacking puppet6-release (6.0.0-23jammy) ...
Setting up puppet6-release (6.0.0-23jammy) ...
root@6d2e2ea018b6:/# apt-get update -y
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:5 http://apt.puppetlabs.com jammy InRelease [113 kB]
Get:6 http://apt.puppetlabs.com jammy/puppet6 all Packages [1316 B]
Get:7 http://apt.puppetlabs.com jammy/puppet6 arm64 Packages [1316 B]
Fetched 452 kB in 1s (417 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
root@6d2e2ea018b6:/# apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@6d2e2ea018b6:/# apt-get install puppet-agent
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package puppet-agent is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'puppet-agent' has no installation candidate
```

What is going wrong?

Possibly important detail: I'm working on a M1 Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

`puppet6-release-jammy.deb` does not contain `puppet-agent` but requires it.

So download and install `puppet-agent` from where you got `puppet6-release-jammy.deb`  The package is ONLY avaliable for 23.04 and 23.10 as you can see on the [packages list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=puppet). So upgrading to 23.04 is an option too. No idea if you can install the 23.04 version into 20.04 (the dependency list seems to be OK)

Comment: puppet6-release-jammy.deb is especially made  (by Puppetlabs) to make Puppet 6 work with this Ubuntu version (hence the name Jammy). So I think it is intended to work for it out of the box? 

It was also the case on Ubuntu 18.04, the apt.puppetlabs.com file for this Ubuntu version provided `puppet-agent`. So it seems to be different for this Ubuntu version then. 

Anyways I will consider switching to different Ubuntu version then.

Comment: No. This is a PPA issue, not Ubuntu. The PPA either is for 23.04 or it is missing a deb for puppet-agent.